# Работа с пакетными менеджерами (изменение файлов)

Tags: php, composer

Добрый день. Я не очень силен в профессиональной (командной) разработке, только учусь, поэтому возникло 2 вопроса:

Допустим, у меня есть какой-то проект на языке *PHP* и с помощью *Composer* я скачиваю какой-то модуль, скажем, для моего сайта на движке *Yii*.

Модуль ставится в папку *Vendor*, туда же вместе с модулем ставится все: виды, контроллеры, модели. Как мне править, допустим, Вид? Если я изменю этот файл (когда он находится в *Vendor*), то все это попадет в *gitignore*, и в итоге моя правка файла не сохранится.

Неужели мне нужно все эти файлы вручную растаскивать по стандартным директориям Вида, Контроллера, Модели (+всю логику и пути корректировать), и это все, чтобы изменить простой php файл? Или эти файлы просто не подлежат правке?

И тогда второй вопрос:
Как мне с моего компьютера перенести весь проект на боевой сервер?

Изначально я весь проект выкладывал на гитхаб, а потом с боевого сервера уже клонировал репозиторий и скачивал зависимости тем же пакетным менеджером. Но ведь Vendor будет в гитигроре?

В чем я заблуждаюсь?

Comment: В vendor файлы не правят.

Comment: А как мне тогда применять скачанный модуль? Вот действительно все вручную переделывать? А если этот модуль обновится? Смысл тогда во всем в этом

Comment: наследование, полиморфизм oop в общем, а вообще во многих фреймворках есть шел с помощью которого вы можете опубликовать view конкретного модуля, так же вы можете переопределить и контроллеры и фабрики всё что вы хотите и унаследоваться от базового класса. Либо заюзать патерны на подобие обсервера.

Comment: Классы да, я могу унаследовать и использовать. А, допустим, View? Это просто кусок PHP-HTML кода. Я же его не унаследую? Мне вообще не стоит пользоваться тем заготовленным View из Vendor? Он там идет как образец, получается? А уже в своем модуле я делаю свой View. 
И, видимо, поэтому во View должно быть меньше всего логики. Я начинаю понимать?

Comment: 1) Мой совет :) переходи на Laravel :) :) :) 2) Раз ты расширяешь класс значит в нем есть метод вызывающий view, создай  view в папке проекта и переопредели вызов